# Pre select the Tab according to Day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to show the tab of the current day without selecting the tab manually? i.e. If today is Monday show the Contents of Monday.
I'm using following code now, where for now , at any conditions  tab 1 ( Sun ) is visible.

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0')">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tue0')">Tue</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,'Wed0')">Wed</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Thu0')">Thu</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Fri0')">Fri</button>
</script>
  



  <script>
document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks').click()
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, all you want to do is have a pre-selected tab based on which day of the week it is, is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct. For now by Default sun has been pre-selected. Here is the screenshot  imgur.com/a/9oNjY, I want to preselect the tab in response to which day it is.

Comment: Would something of this sort work for you? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brGeGV

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre select the Tab according to Day and show its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283440/pre-select-the-tab-according-to-day-and-show-its-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Just store the days of the week in an array and then show whatever tab corresponds to the index of the current day in the array.

This is such a simple operation, JQuery is not helpful.

```js
var days = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"];

// Get all the elements as a node list
var tabButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks");
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".dayTab");

// Get today's day as an index (0-6)
var today = new Date().getDay();
tabButtons[today].classList.add("today");
tabs[today].classList.add("today");
```

```css
/* Do whatever styling you need */
.tablinks { 
  
}

.today {
  background-color:red;
}

.dayTab {
  font-size:.7em;
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0')">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tue0')">Tue</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,'Wed0')">Wed</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Thu0')">Thu</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Fri0')">Fri</button>
</div>

<div id="tabArea">
  <div class="dayTab" id="Sunday">Sunday's stuff</div>
  <div class="dayTab" id="Monday">Monday's stuff</div>
  <div class="dayTab" id="Tuesday">Tuesday's stuff</div>
  <div class="dayTab" id="Wednesday">Wednesday's stuff</div>
  <div class="dayTab" id="Thursday">Thursday's stuff</div>
  <div class="dayTab" id="Friday">Friday's stuff</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't explained well...I have 6 tabs that has routine of each days . Now by default it the first tab is active as the page loads , thus user sees a routine of sun. I want to active the tab for the very same day. if it is monday, the mon0 tab must be active as the page loads instead of visible only.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "active".

Comment: ok here I have a image where as I load the url, http://imgur.com/a/9oNjY Tab with Sun labeled is active and the content of it can be seen. But as today is monday already , I want to show the user see the contents for monday by default instead of sunday i.e Mon tab must get active as the page loads by default and so on for rest other days. I hope I explained well...I'm really terrible in explaining things.

Comment: Till now nothing is been working. Only if I insert [0] at end of tablinks of my original code...it shows sun by default ..other then that none of solution is working .I don't know why am I so bad at explaining things. here is the zip file guys, I hope It will help you to understand with my Problem. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2j3ckof7nFGdUFnMFNxTWdHWU0

Comment: @SagarRawal What happens when you run the code snippet that I posted right here? This code works as you describe.

Comment: I don't Scott, but It didn't showed me anything but here I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283440/pre-select-the-tab-according-to-day-and-show-its-contents/45284766#45284766 Thank for you effort too

Comment: @SagarRawal I don't understand what *"I don't Scott, but It didn't showed me anything"* means. Does my code snippet run for you or not? Also, you should not have posted, essentially the same question a second time. That's really not how Stack Overflow works. I will vote to close this question because of your other one.

Comment: nope I'm sorry but it didn't worked for me and I was stuck in same problem where I was before. It works great in snippets and output is somewhat what I wanted ( though I don't want to show other tab content , as it shows in snippets ) , but when I used it in my code ..It didn't work. I must have done something wrong. But the link I had provided above has a solution of what I really wanted. I hope  I made it clear.

Comment: So, the code does work, here in the snippet. Then, yes, your problem is **not** with this code, but with other code on the page.