# Pre select the Tab according to Day and show its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show the tab of the current day without selecting the tab manually. 
 i.e. If today is Monday show the Contents of Monday.

I'm using following code now, where, for now, at any conditions tab 1 (Sun) is visible.

```
 <div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0')">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tue0')">Tue</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Wed0')">Wed</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Thu0')">Thu</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Fri0')">Fri</button>
```

Code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks').click()
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

and here I have contents that I would like to show when Tab is active and as the page loads are

```
<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent">

<!--Sunday-->
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
</div>

<div id="Mon0" class="tabcontent">

<!--Monday-->
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
 <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
</div>

<div id="Tue0" class="tabcontent">

<!--Tueday-->
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
 <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
</div>

<div id="Wed0" class="tabcontent">

<!--Wenesday-->
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
 <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
</div>

<div id="Thu0" class="tabcontent">

 <!--Thursday-->
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
 <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
</div>

<div id="Fri0" class="tabcontent">

<!-Friday-->
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
 <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sagar,
Here is the example for you to start with jQuery. It is pretty simple, I have used JavaScript object "Date". I have fixed the code only for first 2 or 3 days, you need to make changes on your own. It would be great if you try to fix rest of the code.

```js
var _today = new Date();
var _day = _today.getDay();
switch (_day) {
  case 1:
    $('#Mon0').toggle();
    break;
  case 2:
    $('#Tue0').toggle();
    break;
    // you can keep on adding your case
}

$('.tablinks').click(function() {
  var $target = $(this).data('target');
  $('.tabcontent').hide();
  $($target).toggle();
});
```

```css
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;">
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Sun0">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Mon0">Mon</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Tue0">Tue</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Wed0')">Wed</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Thu0')">Thu</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Fri0')">Fri</button>
</div>

<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Sunday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="Mon0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Monday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <p> Contents of Mon0 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Tue0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Tueday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <p> Contents of Tue0 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Wed0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Wenesday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Thu0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Thursday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="Fri0" class="tabcontent">

  <!--Friday-->
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your script code

```
var currCity = new Date().toString().split(' ')[0];
document.getElementById(currCity+"0").style.display = "block";
```

Please check this code at fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x3ckk63b/1/

Comment: Thank you Paresh. It works perfectly. One last question, as of now it shows contents of mon but doesn't highlight the mon tab. How can I highlight with some color the active tab when It preloads the contents of it.

Comment: You can give separate id to button like `Mon0Btn` and add class name `active` to particular button.

Comment: will you please help me how should I do this....I sucks at coding as it only has been weeks I've into this and I'm learning by examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
 .active { background: red }
</style>
<div class="tab" style="margin-top: 1.6%;">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun0')">Sun</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mon0')">Mon</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tue0')">Tue</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Wed0')">Wed</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Thu0')">Thu</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Fri0')">Fri</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sat0')">Sat</button>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
<script>
  function openCity(evt, cityName, today) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    if(typeof today == 'undefined') {
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    else {
      tablinks[today].className += " active";
    }
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    var days = ['Sun0', 'Mon0', 'Tue0', 'Wed0', 'Thu0', 'Fri0', 'Sat0'];
    var now = new Date();
    var today = now.getDay();  // returns a number.  0=Sunday, 1=Monday, ...
    openCity(null, days[today], today);
  }
</script>
<div id="Sun0" class="tabcontent">
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <p> Contents of Sun0 </p>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel Delay..I'm out now I'll soon update you how this goes.